# Why does onload fire with a remote image but not with a local one?

Tags: javascript, image

In my (rough, condensed) HTML + JS I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="frame">
    <div id="passepartout">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/Kandinsky_-_Mit_Reiter%2C_1912.jpg/420px-Kandinsky_-_Mit_Reiter%2C_1912.jpg"
       >
      <img id="local" style="width:420px;height:auto;margin:20px;margin-top:20px;position:relative;margin-bottom:0"
           src="./420px-Kandinsky_-_Mit_Reiter%2C_1912.jpg">
      <div style="width:420px;margin:20px;margin-top:0px;position:relative">This is the title</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
$(function(){
    document.querySelector('#local').onload = function(){
         console.log('inside onload')
    }
    document.querySelector('#local').onerror = function(e) { console.log(e) }
})
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

in which the onload event fires if attached to the image wit a remote source, and not when attached to the one with the localhost source.

In other words this

```
 document.querySelector('#remote').onload
```

fires and this

```
 document.querySelector('#local').onload
```

does not.

Why is that?

Comment: How are you loading the HTML? From a localhost webserver or from a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all about timing:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="Lenna.jpg" id="lenna">
  <script>
    document.getElementById('lenna').addEventListener('load', () => console.log('lenna'))
    window.addEventListener('load', () => console.log('window'))
  </script>
</body>
```

`$()` from jQuery means to run on `window.onload`, but your image can be loaded before you whole document is ready. It will never happen again if it is already triggered, before the listener is attached.

Simply moving your code outside `$()` would solve the problem. It is totally ok to do so because your `<script>` is at the end of your document.

And I would suggest give up jQuery and use the native DOM APIs instead. It is realy really good.

P.S.:
And yeah, it is ok to have a html 5 document omitting the `html` tags, as long as it is html 5 instead of xhtml.